# Install old version of Gfortran on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, fortran

How to install Gfortran 4.5 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Fortran versions are typically 77, 90, 95, etc. Did you mean the compiler version? If yes, I assume you are asking about Gfortran?

Comment: Yes I mean gfortran

Comment: Just search for Gfortran source code and look in the repositories. Shorcut: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#GNU.2BAC8-Linux

Answer (score 0):

This fortran version [was available](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu) in Ubuntu 11.04.
I can suggest to create [schroot](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot) with 11.04 and install old fortran here:

```
sudo apt-get install schroot debootstrap -y

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/schroot/chroot.d/natty.conf
[natty]
description=Ubuntu 11.04
directory=/srv/chroot/natty
root-users=$USER
type=directory
users=$USER
EOF

sudo mkdir -p /srv/chroot/natty
sudo debootstrap --no-check-gpg natty /srv/chroot/natty

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /srv/chroot/natty/etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
EOF

schroot -c natty -u root apt-get update
schroot -c natty -u root apt-get install gcc gfortran
```

Then execute your program inside the schroot by using command like:

```
schroot -c natty /home/user/old-program
```

or compile it by

```
cd /home/user/source-code
schroot -c natty make
```